# CakePhp isAuthorized, ony two field in $user value

Tags: cakephp

i'm using Cakephp 2.5.5 and i'm stuck with isAuthorized() function.

here is my function:

```
function isAuthorized($user)
{
    debug($user);
    if (!isset($this->request->params['prefix']))
        return (true);
    else if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] == 'admin')
        return (true);
    return (false);
}
```

The problem is that $user['role'] is undefined, the output of debug() is:

```
array(
'User' => array(
    'password' => '*****',
    'username' => 'theUser'
))
```

I don't understand what's wrong, i'm following the book and a video and i don't have the same result T__T. Why i don't have all my user fields? Is there any way to get them?

Comment: You need to share the code that sets the $user variable.

Comment: I'm using isAuthorized() like in the the book:
function isAuthorized($user){...}
i don't know where $user is defined, i suppose it's a cakephp routine

Comment: Does your user table have the role column?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this code?

```
// app/Controller/AppController.php

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ),
        'authorize' => array('Controller') // Added this line
    )
);

public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // Admin can access every action
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}

// app/Controller/PostsController.php

public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // All registered users can add posts
    if ($this->action === 'add') {
        return true;
    }

    // The owner of a post can edit and delete it
    if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))) {
        $postId = (int) $this->request->params['pass'][0];
        if ($this->Post->isOwnedBy($postId, $user['id'])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

[CakeBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

You can use too the beforeFilter function:

//In AppController

```
public function isAuthorized($user) 
{
    // Sudo can access every action
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}
```

//In other controller

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    if ($this->Auth->user('role') === 'admin')
    {
        $this->Auth->allow('all');
    }
    else
    {
       //....
    }
}
```

You have to use in this case, the Auth component, by adding to your controller

```
    public $components = array(
                            'Auth' => array('loginRedirect' => 
                                                array('controller' => '/', 'action' => 'home'),
                                            'logoutRedirect' => 
                                                array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout')
                                           )
                            );
```

Also you might verify that you have a column in your db with role as column name